# Node js: res.json not displaying anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to fetch all the data (users) from a localdb using mongodb and node.js. but res.json(usersArray) is not displaying anything. I also tried to use .render but it would give me another error.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost/mydb', ['users']);
var app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("I received a GET request")


    /*
    db.users.find(function(err, docs){
        console.log("Getting data from db");
        console.log(docs);
        //res.json(docs);
    });
    */

    let usersArray = db.users.find().toArray(function(err, docs){
        console.log("Getting data from db");
        console.log(docs);
        //res.json(docs);
    });;

    res.json(usersArray);

    //usersString = JSON.stringify(usersArray);

    //res.render(usersString);

    //res.json(usersString);

    console.log("Returned data");

});

app.listen(port,'0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running on port '+port);
```

Comment: Why did you comment out `res.json(docs)`? The MongoDB find is *asynchronous*, `usersArray` is probably `undefined` (or maybe a promise).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: because res.json(docs) would just return an empty array and also I can use res.json only once in the program.

Comment: 1. Then there aren't any users to find; and 2. only once *in that handler*, and that's true for any request; why would you want to use it more than once?

Answer (score 1):

use `async`  `await` to block promise-based asynchronous functions

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res){
    console.log("I received a GET request")


    let usersArray = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.users.find().toArray((err, docs) => {
        if (err)
         reject(err)
        resolve(docs)
      })

   });

   res.json(usersArray);

    //usersString = JSON.stringify(usersArray);

    //res.render(usersString);

    //res.json(usersString);

    console.log("Returned data");

});
```

Comment: need to promisify the method first.

Comment: let usersArray = await db.users.find().toArray(); when i use it like that i am getting the error cb is not a function. so toArray() is expecting a callback ?

Comment: i recommend using https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native it supports promised based api

Comment: I recommend using the following library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb It supports async/await and the answer above seems quite logical.